# Law of Large Numbers and Central Limit Theorem

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

Decide whether the law of large numbers and central limit theorem holds for the mutually independent variable $X_k$ with the distribution defined as follows:
$$P\left[{X_k=\pm2^k}\right]=2^{-(2k+1)}$$

Comment: And what did you decide?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? This is not "post your  homework, get it done for free".

Comment: Here is how far I have gone: I understand this problem to be that of a throwing a coin such that the $n^{th}$ throw is biased. Other than that I'm truly stuck.

Comment: $\mathbb{P}[X_k = \pm 2^k] = 2^{-(2k+1)}$ does not define a distribution since $$\mathbb{P}[X_k \in \mathbb{R}] = \mathbb{P}[X_k = 2^k]+\mathbb{P}[X_k = -2^k] = 2^{-2k} \not= 1$$ for $k \geq 1$

Comment: @DavideGiraudo I guess that you guess that $P(X_k=0)=1-2^{-2k}$.

Comment: @Did Right (so my comment is no longer relevant).

Comment: I've removed the [tag:limit] tag, since this tag is intended for questions about evaluations of limits - see the [tag-excerpt](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/limit/info).

Answer (score 3):

Assume that $\mathbb P(X_k=x_k)=\mathbb P(X_k=-x_k)=u_k$, $\mathbb P(X_k=0)=1-2u_k$, for any nonnegative sequence $(x_k)$ and some sequence $(u_k)$ with values in $[0,\frac12)$ such that $\sum\limits_ku_k$ converges.

Then Borel-Cantelli lemma indicates that $X_k\ne0$ for only finitely many indexes $n$, almost surely. Setting $S_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$, one sees that $(S_n)$ is almost surely bounded. In particular, $\frac1nS_n\to0$ almost surely (the law of large numbers holds) and $\frac1{\sqrt{n}}S_n\to0$ almost surely, hence in distribution (the central limit theorem holds, with a degenerate limit).

**Note:** (1) In the exercise $u_n=2^{-2n-1}$ hence $\sum\limits_ku_k$ converges. (2) The proof above does not use the independence property. (3) This assumes that $X_k$ is either $x_k$ or $-x_k$ or $0$, something which is not confirmed yet by the OP, despite several proddings to this effect in the comments.